# Dynamically change application.properties values in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently i am working on a REST based project in Spring Boot. 
I have added the api url in 'application.properties' file.

i.e.

### application.properties

```
api-base-url=http://localhost:8080/RestServices/v1
```

And also this 'api-base-url' value access from java.

In some situations i need to change the 'api-base-url' dynamically.
I have change 'api-base-url' value dynamically & working fine.

But my problem is that
when wildfly restart then the configuration will be reset to default.

i.e
This is my default value

```
api-base-url=http://localhost:8080/RestServices/v1
```

dynamically change to

```
api-base-url=http://10.34.2.3:8080/RestServices/v1
```

when wildfly restart then the configuration will be reset to default.
i.e.

```
api-base-url=http://localhost:8080/RestServices/v1
```

Have any solution for this?

Comment: I think you will have to save it somewhere, then read it back when the server restarts - a file, if you can write to one, a table in a database that you have access to, am Amazon S3 bucket, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @moilejter suggests, one possible way is to persist in database table and at start time you simply read from that table instead of application.properties file. Your application.properties files can hold information necessary for database connection.

You would also need a JMX method or a REST API to trigger in your application that the  url has changed and which inturn, would simply read from same table. This way you would be safe even if app restarts and you won't lose the override.

You can use BeanFactoryPostProcessor coupled with Environment bean to leverage spring placeholder concept.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using a cloud config server to host your config. Two examples are `Spring Cloud Config` and `Consul`.

These servers will host your application's configuration and your spring boot application will make a call out to the config server on start up to get it's config.

`spring-boot-actuator` exposes the endpoint `/refresh` which forces the application to refresh it's configuration. In this case, it will call out to the config server to get the latest version.

This way you can change the config hosted in the config server then hit the `/refresh` endpoint and the changes will be picked up by your application.

Comment: Though this solution will work. But it's an overkill, if application is not cloud-ready.

Comment: I do not know the current size or scope of the application/system the poster is working on. If it is fairly small then I completely agree with you, this may be overkill. However, this is a valid solution to the problem presented by the poster even if it may not be the most suited the their current situation. I'll leave that up to the poster to decide.

Answer (score -11):

@user2214646

Use spring expression language

Comment: There is no explanation as to how this will help!