# Reload properties without stopping and restart Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have application.properties file,which i am using in code to fetch properties.I need to make changes to the property without explicitly stopping and starting the application jar file. I use Dev-tools in STS IDE ,but it doesnt work when jar is ran via java -jar <<>> .

I do not want to include spring cloud config or any DB as it is overkill for my application. Please suggest any other out of the box solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically change application.properties values in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567260/dynamically-change-application-properties-values-in-spring-boot)

Comment: the linked question has solution related to DB and cloud config server. I dont want to implement it that way

Comment: You should probably be clear about what you want. Is it that you don’t want to use spring cloud config server? There are plenty of ways go implement the solution you want but it’s up to you to be clear with your ask and full details about what you do or don’t want before posting your question.

Comment: @RobScully :edited

Answer (score 0):

use `commons-configuration` dependency to reload your properties file and run given code when you need to reflect your properties file changes.

```
    Path rootLocation =  Paths.get("properties file location");
    PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration(rootLocation.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    config.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
    config.get<DatatypeOfPropertyField>("propertyName");
```

I am also doing same thing. I am using external properties file. When my application starts, initializing properties to property bean class when changes occurs, executing above code and setting changes in property bean.

Comment: so when u say execute above code ,r u running this by exposing a seperate REST controller and by invoking the same ?

Comment: @darshan kamat yes