# Programatically changing the application.properties file at runtime with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to overwrite the application.properties file at runtime and then reload it with Spring Boot?

Can I simply update the file like I would any other? How do I tell Spring to reload the new configuration values?

I'm not looking to simply override the properties at runtime, I need to persist the changes back to the original file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The /actuator/refresh endpoint will do the job.
You need to annotate your class (the one that holds the property you want to reload) with the @RefreshScope annotation.

So basically modify your application.properties file, then invoke that endpoint and its done.

Please find this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html) with more info about the actuator.

This other [link](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-commons-parent/1.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.html) with more details on @RefreshScope.

Comment: That should do it. Cheers

Comment: i have not tested it if your properties file is located inside your jar. With an external properties file it should work without problems. Please check this post too just in case https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties

Comment: you can follow this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567260/dynamically-change-application-properties-values-in-spring-boot

Comment: @Carlos I am planning on having an external file so that should be fine